# C# How much memory is used by an array if only some entries are initialized?

Tags: c#

The question was arisen about an array of objects when it's more in the source code than it's required. For example, I have Button objects like this(not initialized yet):

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[99]
```

So the question is that if I create and initialize say for instance only 10 of them, will there be any additional memory consumption because of the 99 array of buttons?

Comment: the array will hold its size to the references - it depends if `Button` is a value or reference type

Comment: If you don't know how many buttons you'll use, you can consider using a List. It'll double in size once a certain limit is reached.

Comment: @daniel-a-white, what do you mean by if it's value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: Yes, some additional space will be wasted - but it's not very much.

Assuming a `Button` is a reference type, the space used for the array is `numberOfElements` * `size of a reference` when you first create the array without creating any `Button` objects.

The size of a reference is, of course, 32 bits when running as a 32-bit process and 64 bits when running as a 64-bit process.

So for your example with 10 buttons in an array sized for 99, the total space taken for a 64-bit process would be:

```
Size of the array + 10 * (size of a Button)
```

Where the size of the array would be 99 * size of a reference, or 99 * 8 (bytes).

(The 8 bytes in that calculation is because 64 bits == 8 bytes)

Comment: @ДмитрийИгнатьев See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/arrayshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/arrays) for example. `The new operator automatically initializes the elements of an array to their default value, which, for example, is zero for all numeric types and null for all reference types.` - this tells you that all the elements are initialised to a null reference, from which you can tell the size of the array will be `#elements * sizeof(reference)`